# PDE introductory

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need some help on the following PDE using separation of variables:

$$\frac {\delta U}{\delta t}+U =\frac {\delta^2U}{\delta x^2 }, 0<x<\pi, t>0 $$
Given that
$$ U(0,t)=U(\pi,t)=0, t>0 $$
$$U(x,0)=x(\pi-x), 0<x<\pi$$ 
My attempt, let;
$$ U = X T $$
Then
$$ XT'+XT=X''T $$
$$\frac {T'+T}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-k^2 $$
Solving ODE with $X$
$$X(x)=A\cos kx+B\sin kx$$
$$X(0)=A=0$$
$$X(\pi)=B\sin k\pi=0$$
$B=0$ or $\sin k\pi=0$ take the non trivial case $\sin k\pi=0$
$$k=n, n=1,2,3....$$ 
$$X(x)=B\sin nx$$
Solving ODE with $T$
$$\frac {T'+T}{T}=\frac{T'}{T}+1=-k^2 $$
$$T(t)=Ce^{-t(n^2+1)}$$
$$U(x,t)=B\sin nx \cdot Ce^{-t(n^2+1)}, BC=C$$
By the principle of superposition:
$$U(x,t) = \sum C_n \sin nx \cdot e^{-t(n^2+1)}, $$
$$U(x,0) = \sum C_n \sin nx = x(\pi-x)$$
And now solve using fourier sine series. If this is complete garbage could somebody point me in the right direction or perhaps where I have gone wrong only just started PDE's so would be nice to have some constructive input, thanks as always and feel free to edit my late night mistakes.

Comment: Just find the coefficients $C_{n}$ and the job is done.

Comment: Thank you for your input I thought this was the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} x(\pi - x) \, \sin(n x) \, dx = \frac{2(1-(-1)^{n})}{n^{3}}$$
then 
\begin{align}
U(x,t) &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - (-1)^{n}}{n^{3}} \, \sin(n x) \, e^{- (n^{2}-1) \, t} \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{3}} \, \sin((2n+1) \, x) \, e^{- ((2n+1)^{2}-1) \, t} \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{3}} \, \sin((2n+1) \, x) \, e^{- 4 \, n (n+1) \, t}  
\end{align}

Comment: Would there not be a $\frac {1}{\pi}$ as a constant multiple of the integral for the fourier sine series? or is that what you've included outside the sum in your second term?

Comment: @pi-e There is, but here I only stated the integral and value. I added the $\frac{1}{\pi}$ value when used in the series.

Comment: Yes that's fair enough, why did you choose to re-evaluate the term n=1 in the series to n=0 is that common? could we not just say $U(x,t) = 0$ when n is even and otherwise when not?

Comment: @pi-e It is common to reduce $1 \pm (-1)^{n}$ to the most most compact form. Only the odd terms are non-zero in this series. This is why the index changed.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight Leucippus much appreciated I wasn't aware that reduction was commonplace.